# Making onClickListener a static method

Tags: android, onclicklistener

```
View.OnClickListener ocl = new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.ocl_action();
    }

    public void ocl_action() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++){                               }
            Toast.makeText(ControllerProjMain.this,"hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
        }
    }
};
```

It does not work if I just call `ocl.ocl_action();`

Comment: just define your ocl_action() outside of the listener's body and lose the "this."

Comment: @DavidCDong I have added an answer check if that works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Define ocl_action() function outside listener body and remove keyword 'this' while function calling.

Answer (score 0):

See for changes at your code. You need to define the method `ocl_action` outside the listener.

```
View.OnClickListener ocl = new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.ocl_action();
    }};

public void ocl_action() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  for(int i=0; i<5;i++){                              
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, pull your function outside of the `onClick()` method. Inside `onClick()` method `this` will not point your activity. So remove `this` while you are making a function call.

```
View.OnClickListener ocl = new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v) {
    ocl_action();
}};

public void ocl_action() {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  for(int i=0; i<5;i++){                              
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
  }
}
```